# Why do I exceed the quota of Youtube Api v3

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I receive error 403 which is exceeding quota although I'm still in the testing phase which is using one device and I'm the only one using it plus the project is on billing level so it charges me if there is any exceeding the quota, on another note what will happen when I release the app and have like 1000 + users?

Comment: Please edit your question and include exactly what quota you are exceeding, we need the full error message.     1. billing has nothing to do with YouTube API its free to use,  2. You should begin the verification process now it takes a long time to go though.  3. You should apply for a quota extension now as the process takes a long time to go though.

Comment: Hi Dalm, thank you so much, I cannot give you now the error message as the daily quota has been reset now so I can use it, how can I start the 2nd and 3rd process I have searched for such a thing online and I didn't find any results for that

Comment: They can both be found in Google developer console.  Where you enabled the Youtube api you can find quota and apply for the extension.  Where you set up your consent screen you can find information about applying for application verification.   Remember any videos you upload will be private until you pass verification.

Comment: ok thanks, for the 1st one I got it, they request to make the payment of 10$ which is ok, the 2nd one I don't get it, I will not upload videos through the youtube api I will get my videos from the channels that I'm already owning, so do I still need this verification?